# Mail property needed for helo

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

The sysad gave this to me as I cannot use our SMTP server.

[image]

Stacktrace:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.value-exch.com, port: 25, response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
```

Should I add anything besides this ones? Like for the helo?

```
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host); 
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
```

Comment: How do you connect using a mail client?

Comment: Can you telnet to the server?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, just eclipse and catchwa yes I can telnet

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're asking how to set the "helo" value when using JavaMail.  If that's your question, then the answer is to set the [`mail.smtp.localhost`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.localhost) property.

(If that's not your question, then please ask again.)

Comment: added  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.localhost", "value.test"); and still not working

Comment: Can you add more detail?  What **exactly** is not working?  What happens?  What did you expect to happen?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  What other debugging did you do to determine why it's not working?

Comment: same error as the one listed above. Im reaching out to our sys admin for more info but thats the only configuration he gave me.

Comment: Did you try the [JavaMail connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug)?  And again, what does the JavaMail debug output show?

Comment: Upvote for indicating how to set the `HELO` property.